# Assign a string from a php file to a UIlabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a response string being returned to my xcode app from a php file on a server. Is there anyway that I can assign the text of the response string to the text of a UIlabel?

My code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var firstnameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastnameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLbl: UILabel!


@IBAction func TextFieldEditingDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "usernamecheck.php")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    print("Request: \(request)")
    let postString = "username=\(usernameTxt.text!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        } // Ends errror If statements
        print("response = \(response)")
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

    } // Ends let task
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: where is the label?

Comment: btw, `NSURL(string: "usernamecheck.php")` is not a valid url so it'll crash.

Comment: The label is in the view controller. And usernamecheck.php isn't the full url. I just didn't include it for security reasons..

Comment: Loading the same data from a remote server every time the user changes the text in a text field seems to me like a very bad idea. @OzgurVatansever explained **how** to do it, but I submit that the way you're doing it is ill advised. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: And by the way, function names should start with a lower case letter. So your TextFieldEditingDidChange method should be `textFieldEditingDidChange(_:)` instead.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to do this is so that when the user is choosing a username, it can notify the user if the username has been chosen already. Why do you think this is a very bad idea?